# Dragging jQuery dialog past viewport

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using jQuery dialog and have problems dragging the dialog partially outside of the viewport.

The demo for the Draggable does exactly what I want:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/default.html

But the demo for the Dialog doesn't allow the dialog to be moved partially outside of the viewport:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/default.html

How to make the Dialog to allow dragging partially off the viewport?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the jQuery UI dialog box by changing the containment. The default value is 'document'.

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function () {
    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        containment: false
    });
};
```